# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms_json'" when installing Apache Superset

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-superset, wtforms-json

I am trying to install Apache Superset on EC2 but I get this error when I run this command:

```
fabmanager create-admin --app superset
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms_json'

I am following the steps mentioned here:
https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/dedd0ee8221f4b155592149d08a26248

Answer (score 1):

The instructions in the gist you are referencing are not official and/or maintained by the community. They appear to be dated as the proper pypi package is `apache-superset` (as in `pip install apache-superset`).

Find the official installation documentation with installation instructions here: https://superset.apache.org/docs/intro